# Transform data calculated via formulas into static values

Tags: excel

The way I have been using excel to transform data calculated via formulas into static values was to select each cell, press `F2` to edit it and then press `F9`to replace the content of that cell with the result of the formula in it.

I was wondering if there is a convenient way to do this process to a group of selected cells. It would come in handy if I wanted to do this to hundreds of cells at a time.

Could anybody please tell me if that is possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a VBA based solution is viable, then this short routine should suffice.

```
sub Values_Only()
    with selection
        .value = .value
    end with
end sub
```

Just select a group of cells and tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> then **Run** the macro. Optionally, use <kbd>Options</kbd> in the **Macros** dialog to set a hot key combination.

You may also find the **Quick Access Toolbar** (aka QAT) of use to assign the **Paste Values** command to a hotkey. Mine is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. With any group of cells selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is sufficient to revert formulas to their returned values. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/840143/is-there-a-way-to-autofill-cells-in-excel-2013-with-keyboard-shortcuts/840169#840169) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight all of the desired cells. Copy them. Then right click the highlighted area and select the 123 paste option.